# How do I resolve additional post request in onSubmit method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, onsubmit

I want in React's onSubmit method call a post request using axios and basing on that post request's result prevent form submit.

```
const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
  const data: IName = {
     name: ""
  };

  try {
    axios.post<IName>(`/api/saveName`, data)
      .catch((err) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
  } catch (err) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
};

return (
  <>
    <form action={myApi} name="MyName" method="post" onSubmit={onSubmit} >
  </>
);
```

event.preventDefault is never fired because promise is not resolved before leaving onSubmit

Comment: Since `axios.post` is async, you have to 1. prevent the submit event no matter what 2. call `submit()` on the form yourself if it checks out (which skips `onsubmit`)

Comment: You can not do it this way, event default actions don’t “wait” for any async stuff or promises. You need to prevent the default right away, and then _explicitly_ submit your form via JS.

Comment: " and then explicitly submit your form via JS." I cannot do this because of external api which form is beeing post to, where I face problem with CORS

Answer (score 0):

Change onSubmit method to async function to use async/await pattern

```
onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
  const data: IName = {
     name: ""
  };

  try {
    await axios.post<IName>(`/api/saveName`, data)
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle error
  }
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to use **useRef** and call **submit()** on form with external button's **onClick** handler.

Example:

```
const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
  const data: IName = {
   name: ""
  };

  axios.post<IName>(`/api/saveName`, data)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200 && form.current) {
        form.current.submit();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
};

return (
  <>
    <form action={myApi} name="MyName" method="post" onSubmit={onSubmit} >
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>Send Form</button>
  </>
);
```